# python dictionary, assigning lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello all i have an assignment for my computer science class where i have to emulate a different version of Conway game of life: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life

( in short, the user enters with a set of coordinates with the 'alive' cells, then the user enters the size of the board, then how many times the program will be iterated. For each iteration a dead cell becomes alive if it is surrounded by a set number of cells, and a alive cell dies if it is not surrounded by a set number of alive cells)

My idea for this is to implement a dictionary with two keys: Coordinates, receiving a list of coordinates, and status, receiving a string (either 'Live or 'dead') But i am having a hard time implementing this. First of all i have to create a dictionary the size of the board entered by the user , with n lines and m columns. Second the first key of my dictionary , 'Coordinates', has to receive all the coordinates of the board.

Is this method even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That method sounds complicated. The usual way to do this sort of thing is to use 2D arrays, which you can implement using a list of lists. So your outer list would contain n inner lists, each of those lists would contain a row of m cells. Set dead cells to False and live cells to True. You actually need 2 2D arrays, one for the current state and one for the updated state.

Comment: You _could_ do it with a set of tuples, with each tuple in the set holding the coordinates of a live cell. That would use RAM more efficiently, especially for sparse patterns, but I suggest that you try doing it with a 2D list first.

Comment: I have a tendency to go for the hardest solution first :/

Specially when i have a multidimensional array problem to solve, i absolutely hate them.
And while my solution seems harder to implement at first ,i think  it is going to make easier to check the status of the cell neighbors and implement the necessary changes to the cells ( maybe i am wrong here).

Comment: But thanks! If i fail to implement my method i am going to go with the 2d arrays.

Comment: Ok, but please use a set instead of a list. A list of coordinates will be **much** slower to search than a set of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You might use this approach to get input

```
m=5
n=5

#Generate m*n board with all cells Dead
board=[["Dead" for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)] 

#Input list with alive cells
alivelist=[[0,0],[2,3],[4,4]]
print board
# [['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead']]

#Block to mark cells Alive
for x in alivelist:
    board[x[0]][x[1]]="Alive"
print board

# [['Alive', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Alive', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead'], 
# ['Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Dead', 'Alive']]
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a great solution!!